# Magento - Custom Extension causing 404 errors

Tags: php, xml, magento, config

Recently I've been having '404 error page not found' errors pop up in my admin. After trying every solution online to no extent I have found out at least what is causing the error.

As soon as I disabled my custom extension all the 404 error pages went away.

I think it may be due to the config of my extension which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Pinto_PartnerSystem>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Pinto_PartnerSystem>
    </modules> 

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <partnersystemblock1>
                <class>Pinto_PartnerSystem_Block</class>
            </partnersystemblock1>  
            <partnersystemblock2>
                <class>Pinto_PartnerSystem_Block_EditSpecial</class>
            </partnersystemblock2> 
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <partnersystemhelper>
                <class>Pinto_PartnerSystem_Helper</class>
            </partnersystemhelper>
        </helpers>
    </global>    

    <admin>
        <routers>
           <partnersystem>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Pinto_PartnerSystem_AdminControllers</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>

                    <modules>
                        <sintax after="Pinto_PartnerSystem_AdminControllers">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
           </partnersystem>          
         </routers>     
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
             <partnersystem translate="title" module="partnersystemhelper">
                <title>Partner System</title>
                <sort_order>42</sort_order>
                <children>
                <!-- Note the misleading "module" attribute. 
                    It actualy refers to one of the declared helpers -->

                    <myitem1 translate="title" module="partnersystemhelper">
                        <title>Manage Partners</title>
                        <action>partnersystem/partners</action>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem1>

                    <myitem2 translate="title" module="partnersystemhelper">
                        <title>Manage Partner Groups</title>
                        <action>partnersystem/settings</action>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem2>

                    <myitem3 translate="title" module="partnersystemhelper">
                        <title>View My Balance</title>
                        <action>partnersystem/balance</action>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem3>

                    <myitem4 translate="title" module="partnersystemhelper">
                        <title>Add Partner</title>
                        <action>partnersystem/addpartner</action>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem4>

                    <myitem5 translate="title" module="partnersystemhelper">
                        <title>Add Partner Group</title>
                        <action>partnersystem/addpartnergroup</action>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem5>

                </children>
             </partnersystem>
        </menu>

        <acl><!-- permits -->
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <partnersystem translate="title" module="partnersystemhelper"><!-- this tag matches the menu tag, and the same for his children -->
                        <title>Partner System</title>
                        <children>
                            <myitem1>
                                <title>Manage Partners</title>
                            </myitem1>
                            <myitem2>
                                <title>Manage Partner Groups</title>
                            </myitem2>
                            <myitem3>
                                <title>View My Balance</title>
                            </myitem3>
                        </children>
                    </partnersystem>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

Could someone please scan over the XML contents and see if anythings wrong?

I'm quite new to Magento and this error has been stressing me out a lot recently so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the '404 error page not found' errors do not show up in my extension - my extension all displays fine. They start showing up at places like the index management, compilation and certain configuration pages.

Comment: Did you tried logout and login again..?Whenever you install new admin module in magento you need to logout and login again. Because in admin module you should configure <acl>...</acl> (Access control list) section for giving permission for all controllers that you declared in your module..

Comment: I forgot to mention that the 404 errors don't show up in my extension when I activate it but in random places like the index management or certain other configuration pages. Logging out and in and clearing the cache doesn't fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i think a full refresh using F5 might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning caché, then logout and login again?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the 404 errors don't show up in my extension when I activate it but in random places like the index management or certain other configuration pages. Logging out and in and clearing the cache doesn't fix this.